# Check if Integer is between a range of column values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Consider the following table schema:

```
----------------------------------
|  ID  |  MinValue  |  MaxValue  |
----------------------------------
|  1   |      0     |    10      |
|  2   |     11     |    20      |
|  3   |     21     |    30      |
```

I want to be able to pass an integer, and have it return the appropriate ID where that value matches the range between Min and Max Value.

EG:

```
Input = 17
Output = 2

Input = 4
Output = 1

Input = 26
Output = 3
```

I thought I could do something like:

```
SELECT ID FROM MyTable WHERE MinValue >= @input AND MaxValue <= @input
```

But it doesn't work, nothing is returned.

I'm sure the solution is blatantly simple, but i'm stumped.

What's the best way to achieve this in SQL Server?

Comment: ... `where @input between MinValue and MaxValue`.

Comment: You were close: `MinValue <= @input AND MaxValue >= @input`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT ID FROM MyTable WHERE @input BETWEEN MinValue AND MaxValue
```

**DESCRIPTION of BEETWEEN**

The SQL `BETWEEN` Condition is used to retrieve values within a range in a `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE` statement.

**SYNTAX**

The syntax for the SQL `BETWEEN` Condition is:

expression `BETWEEN value1 AND value2`;
Parameters or Arguments

expression is a column or calculation.

`value1` and `value2` create an inclusive range that expression is compared to.

**NOTE**

The SQL `BETWEEN` Condition will return the records where expression is within the range of `value1` and `value2` (inclusive).

ref: http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/between.php

or you can also use like

```
MinValue <= @input AND MaxValue >= @input
```

Answer (score 11):

Try this,

```
SELECT ID FROM MyTable WHERE @input BETWEEN MinValue AND MaxValue.
```

Or flip the equality signs in your statement.

```
SELECT ID FROM MyTable WHERE MinValue <= @input AND MaxValue >= @input
```

Answer (score 2):

Use BETWEEN

```
SELECT ID 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE @input BETWEEN MinValue AND MaxValue
```